# Why would you use GHC RTS option -V0?

Tags: haskell, ghc

According to the ghc runtime control doc, if you use the **`-V0`** option the *timer signal is disabled*.

Can someone explain to me why would you do such a thing?

Eg: `ghc +RTS -V0 -RTS -rtsopts -O2 -o Solution Solution.hs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last paragraph from the [docs](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/profiling.html#rts-flag--V%20%E2%9F%A8secs%E2%9F%A9) hints at a possible reason: context switching becomes deterministic and that can help debugging.

> -V ⟨secs⟩
> Default:  0.02
>
> Sets the interval that the RTS clock ticks at, which is also the sampling interval of the time and allocation profile. The default is
> 0.02 seconds. The runtime uses a single timer signal to count ticks; this timer signal is used to control the context switch timer (Using
> Concurrent Haskell) and the heap profiling timer RTS options for heap
> profiling. Also, the time profiler uses the RTS timer signal directly
> to record time profiling samples.
>
> Normally, setting the -V ⟨secs⟩ option directly is not necessary: the resolution of the RTS timer is adjusted automatically if a short
> interval is requested with the -C ⟨s⟩ or -i ⟨secs⟩ options. However,
> setting -V ⟨secs⟩ is required in order to increase the resolution of
> the time profiler.
>
> Using a value of zero disables the RTS clock completely, and has the
> effect of disabling timers that depend on it: the context switch timer
> and the heap profiling timer. Context switches will still happen, but
> deterministically and at a rate much faster than normal. Disabling the
> interval timer is useful for debugging, because it eliminates a source
> of non-determinism at runtime.

I guess using `-V0` also makes SIGALRM / SIGVTALRM available to the application. Normally that is reserved by the run time system.